# Word VBA: Find and replace with ref code

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find and replace the brackets and text in it with a field code http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-ref-field-HP005186139.aspx

```
Sub replacereftag()
    ReplacementText "<test>", "REF Test.Test1 "
End Sub

Private Sub ReplacementText(findtext As String, replacetext As String)
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = findtext
        .myrange.Field = replacetext
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the field code ref portion but I have not been successful at this point. It replaces the text but not as a reference file. I am just trying to figure out the reference code

Comment: it's still a bit unclear- are you trying to replace some text within your document with `Field object`?

Comment: Correct a field code: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-ref-field-HP005186139.aspx

Comment: Is this for a mail-merge or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you need to use different kind of logic in your code. The main difference is that you need to find your text first and select it. As a next step you need to add a field in the range of selection. The following subroutines are improved your ones doing all these things. Hope it's what you are looking for. (See some comments inside the code)

```
Sub replacereftag()
    ReplacementText "<test>", "REF Test.Test1 "
    'if you keep .MatchWildcards = True below then call next sub in this way:
    'ReplacementText "\<test\>", "REF Test.Test1 "
End Sub

Private Sub ReplacementText(findtext As String, replacetext As String)
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = findtext
        'I removed something here
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = False '!!!- both <> are special characters!!
    End With

    'looping to search for all occurrences
    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        'add a field here
        Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
            "REF  Test.Test1", PreserveFormatting:=False
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Edit**

```
Sub replacereftag()
    ReplacementText "<test>", "REF Test.Test"

    Dim i
    for i=1 to 10          'change to last number
        ReplacementText "<test" & i & ">", "REF Test.Test" & i
    next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks KazJaw how would you improve the search location I have multiple references that need to be replaced eg. <test> becomes ref test.test and <test1> becomes ref test.test1 etc.